# PHP upgrade to 5.3 from 5.2, sessions no longer get stored

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis-7

background link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014945/php-upgrade-5-2-to-5-3-session-issue

I have upgraded PHP on my 2008 std server from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3. Following the upgrade, sessions no longer work correctly.

I have copied over the settings from my PHP.ini files which are applicable and configure new settings in line with the server or PHP's recommendations.

PHP executes fine correctly, however session data does not get saved.

I have session data stored in c:\temp. For each session created, I can see the session file in this folder. However no information gets written into the session file. 
Permissions wise, IUSR and EVERYONE has write access to this folder.

If I downgrade to PHP 5.2, sessions are saved correctly and the site functions correctly.

I have followed advise to ensure my code is optimised. closing session files correctly and forcing a session reset.

I'm stumped.

```
session 
 
Session Support enabled  
Registered save handlers files user sqlite   
Registered serializer handlers php php_binary wddx   

 
 
DirectiveLocal ValueMaster Value 
session.auto_startOffOff 
session.bug_compat_42OnOn 
session.bug_compat_warnOnOn 
session.cache_expire180180 
session.cache_limiternocachenocache 
session.cookie_domainno valueno value 
session.cookie_httponlyOffOff 
session.cookie_lifetime00 
session.cookie_path// 
session.cookie_secureOffOff 
session.entropy_fileno valueno value 
session.entropy_length00 
session.gc_divisor100100 
session.gc_maxlifetime14401440 
session.gc_probability11 
session.hash_bits_per_character44 
session.hash_function00 
session.namePHPSESSID53PHPSESSID53 
session.referer_checkno valueno value 
session.save_handlerfilesfiles 
session.save_path/temp/temp 
session.serialize_handlerphpphp 
session.use_cookiesOnOn 
session.use_only_cookiesOnOn 
session.use_trans_sid00
```

Comment: Adding the exact version of PHP in your question will be helpful to check against bugs.

Comment: valid point: PHP 5.3.6

Comment: I see a number of session variables deprecated in php 5.3.X. Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php and confirm that you are not using them. If you are not using them in your code and still getting this error, you may need to provide the code snippet for further review as there is no session related bugs reported yet for PHP 5.3.6.

Comment: Thanks, I'll review. Code can be viewed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014945/php-upgrade-5-2-to-5-3-session-issue

Comment: Please add your answer from the SO answer to here, or go ahead and close/delete this so it isn't hanging around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was related to the last session name "(*@#!_D@R*&$%(){*@)_D_296", it was somehow invalidating the entire browser session, removing all data from the session.

After removing "(*@#!_D@R*&$%(){*@)_D_296" from the session name, the login session started working again.

details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014945/php-upgrade-5-2-to-5-3-session-issue